# consuming the string based web service in objective c?

Tags: objective-c

```
  NSString *url = json[0][@"smsapi"];
 int ramdomnumber = arc4random_uniform(900000) + 100000;
 NSString *msg =@"Your%20Etowns%20verification%20code%20is%20";
 NSString *msgstring=[msg stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d ",ramdomnumber];
 NSString *outurl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&mobileNo=%@&msg=%@", url,contactnotextvalue, msgstring];

//calling the web service 
NSURLRequest *Request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:outurl]];
NSURLResponse *resp = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: Request returningResponse: &resp error: &error];
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@ the response......",responseString);
```

In this above code whenever i will pass the static url i am getting the response but when i add that using stringwithformat i am not getting the response it will pass the null value can anyone suggest me what is mistake i am doing in the above code

Comment: First check your outUrl is in correct format. Check it with your static data. There are two reasons two get null response. One is if your sending wrong data and second if there is no data with your request. If there is no data with your request also it will send some responses. So the problem is your sending data. Check it carefully.

Comment: thanks for ur reply sir i check that url by using the rest client it returns the value .also i send the correct values to that web service but i don't no why i am getting the null value

Comment: if put that generated outurl in static format like NSString *test = @"my output string"; and if i set that value to the nsurlrequest it will working fine but when assign that dynamic it will give the empty response

Comment: Can your show your url,mobile no and msg for checking the code and response?

Comment: You are adding a space (`@"%d "`) to your URL. Use `%20` instead, like that: `@"%d%%20"`

Comment: @vitormm thanks for ur reply sir it's working fine